# Prime Video - Foreign Speech Subtitles in Original Language

Tags: amazon, localization, video-streaming, subtitles

I've noticed this with shows that have dialogue in multiple languages. For reference I live in Germany, so on amazon.de there will be shows available in German and "original voice" (usually English), titled `[dt./OV]`. This lets me select English as the audio language and "none" as the subtitle language. When I do this I get no subtitles for regular dialogue. However, speaking in foreign languages, e.g. Spanish, will still be subtitled in German, which is very annoying if I'm trying to watch a show as originally intended. Is there any way to convince Amazon's player to give the complete original experience, including no subtitles and English/original for foreign dialogue?

I suspect the answer will be no since I haven't found any hidden settings, but maybe I missed something. My guess is that Amazon supplies subtitles and audio tracks in multiple languages but only the German render of the video and that these foreign language subtitles are baked into that video file. In that case, I would be very disappointed with Amazon for providing supposedly OV content, but not even bothering to switch the video source to the right language!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is actually right and that is exactly how it is. Most likely Amazon failed in this instance to get original video source (either with awareness or not). As a customer, you are in the right to complain to them.

Comment: That sucks. I doubt this happens because they can't get their hands on the OV video file, since I've noticed this in many different shows and movies. I'm inclined to think they just can't be bothered, and they definitely have the originals available on amazon.co.uk (source: used to live in the UK). But who knows, they might have agreements with the big production companies that categorically forbid sharing the video across regions but not the audio. Seems unlikely to me though.

Comment: using amazon.uk and have yet to see a movie in english where foreign language parts/sections are subtitled in english - 45 mins in on latest, 10 mins before the end of the movie on another an suddenly you just wasted ur time/ruined the movie.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found the same issue watching shows in English in Australia. Spanish is shown in German subtitles. I have to go and change the settings in subtitles from ‘none’ to a language (doesn’t matter which one) and then back to ‘none’. The subtitles then revert to English.

Answer (score 0):

Is a regular thing with Amazon prime - demand your money back if you paid for a movie with this issue. **Check 1 star user reviews before starting to watch** - if missing subtitles are an issue it may be noted there.